# Multiple Questions in a Amazon Mturk HIT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm confused weather to create a separate HIT for each question or put multiple questions in a HIT. Basically, by putting multiple questions, say 10, in a single HIT I want that one user answers all of them. If I create one HIT for each questions then each user will be doing ten HITs. Don't know which is better? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on if you need answers to every question from each worker. If it doesn't matter who answers the questions, or how many of them they answer, then you can make them separate. If you need someone to answer all of them, then it should be one HIT.

Comment: Oh, so there is no hard and fast rule. Thanks indeed @Thomas. I got it now.

Comment: You should also think about the cost you pay a worker per HIT and their willingness to complete a task with 10+ questions. I've found workers are more likely to accept/complete shorter tasks (1-2 questions). Of course, it depends on your study and if you need Turks to complete all items as @Thomas said.